# Python: Gestión de excepciones dentro del método __exit__

Tags: python, excepciones

He creado la siguiente clase para gestionar archivos:

```
'''
Clase (gestor de contexto) para el manejo de archivos .txt
'''

class GestorArchivos:

    def __init__(self, nombre): self.nombre = nombre

    def __enter__(self):

        self.archivo = open(self.nombre, 'a', encoding = 'utf8')

        return self.archivo

    def __exit__(self, tipoError, valorError, trazaError):

        if tipoError: print(f'Ha ocurrido un error al procesar el archivo: (1) {tipoError} (2) {valorError}')

        self.archivo.close()
```

Dado el modo `'a'`, a un archivo abierto con este gestor no se le puede aplicar el método `read()`, por lo que se producirá un error al intentarlo:

```
from auxiliares.GestorArchivos import GestorArchivos as GA

try:
    
    with GA('salidas/pruebas.txt') as archivo:
    
        archivo.write('...')
        archivo.read()
    
except Exception as error: print(f'Ha ocurrido un error: (1) {type(error)} (2) {error}')
```

Sin embargo, la excepción ocurre dos veces:

```
Ha ocurrido un error al procesar el archivo: (1) <class 'io.UnsupportedOperation'> (2) not readable
Ha ocurrido un error: (1) <class 'io.UnsupportedOperation'> (2) not readable
```

¿Por qué no es suficiente con la gestión de excepciones del método `__exit__` y me veo obligado a rodear el bloque `with` con un `try except` para que la "segunda" excepción -que en realidad es la misma que la primera- no detenga el programa?

Comment: No veo dos excepciones. Sólo hay una excepción de la cual generas dos `print`. Si eliminas el `print` dentro del `__exit__()` desparece el problema. Es enteramente correcto que la excepción llegue hasta el código que la invoco; no puede ser de otra manera.

Comment: ¿Entonces no es posible prescindir del `try except` a pesar de utilizar el método `__exit__`?

Comment: El principio básico es que alguien tiene que atrapar las excepciones o el programa se cae.

Comment: Esperaba que de eso se encargase el bloque `with` una vez implementado apropiadamente el método `__exit__`, la verdad.

Comment: Es decir, quiero que de gestionar la excepción se encargue el método `__exit__`, que no necesite implementar un `try except` cada vez que intente abrir un archivo en cualquier parte del código; ¿eso es posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers

> ```
> object.__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
> ```
>
> Exit the runtime context related to this object. The parameters
> describe the exception that caused the context to be exited. If the
> context was exited without an exception, all three arguments will be
> None.
>
> **If an exception is supplied, and the method wishes to suppress the**
> **exception (i.e., prevent it from being propagated), it should return a**
> **true value**. Otherwise, the exception will be processed normally upon
> exit from this method.

Ahora funciona como quiero:

```
'''
Clase (gestor de contexto) para el manejo de archivos .txt
'''

class GestorArchivos:

    def __init__(self, nombre): self.nombre = nombre

    def __enter__(self):

        self.archivo = open(self.nombre, 'a', encoding = 'utf8')

        return self.archivo

    def __exit__(self, tipoError, valorError, trazaError):

        self.archivo.close()

        if tipoError:

            print(f'Ha ocurrido un error al procesar el archivo: (1) {tipoError} (2) {valorError}')

            return True
```

Y sin necesidad de `try except`:

```
from auxiliares.GestorArchivos import GestorArchivos as GA

with GA('salidas/pruebas.txt') as archivo:

    archivo.write('...')
    archivo.read()
```

Sólo obtengo el mensaje de `__exit__` y el programa no se detiene:

```
Ha ocurrido un error al procesar el archivo: (1) <class 'io.UnsupportedOperation'> (2) not readable
```